# How to get the certificate chain from azure keyvault

Tags: java, azure, azure-keyvault

I uploaded a pfx file to Azure Key Vault that has 2 parent certificates in its chain.  I can get the base certificate with a call to KeyVaultClient.getCertificate(cert_id).

```
Certificate cert = new X509CertImpl(m_Client.getCertificate(m_CertId).cer());
```

The problem is I need the entire certificate chain. Is there a way to do this using the Java api?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

- import pre-generated certificate file into AKV (**.PEM** format, contains 2 certificates and private key. Presence of private key is required by AKV);
- load certificate by Java API --> got 1 certificate only;
- load secret by Java API --> got 2 certificates and private key;

Probably this behavior depends on AKV settings (at least documentation says that key might be marked as exportable or not) and certificate format.

This [Microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/about-certificates#exportable-or-non-exportable-key) was useful for me.

Answer (score -3):

After you have uploaded a certificate to keyvault, it is no longer possible to access the private key, or any part of the certificate chain. Basically the certificate is split into its key (which cannot be retrieved from KV) and the cert.

If you need to access those you would need to create a secret from the encoded pfx file. i.e. a base64 of the cert file. If you need to keep the key safe, you could just create a KV secret from a certificate with the parents attached. i.e. base64 it, and save it to KV as a secret.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? When I uploaded the pfx file it created a certificate, a key, and a secret.  So if I'm able to get the secret is there a way to get the chain from that? i.e. I can call: SecretBundle secret = m_Client.getSecret("https: //myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/Chain/secretid");

Comment: What!? You absolutely *can* access the private key. That's what the Key Vault is for, to store secrets like private keys in X.509 certificates.